# Jquery when the user hits bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I've been working on a scroll to top function for my website, and that part of it works fine. My problem is however that I have a fixed div that is overlapping my footer when it hits the bottom of the page.

Here is the function that I have working.

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= 800) {
    $('#beamUp').show(1000);
         } else {
    $('#beamUp').hide(1000);
    return false;
  }  
});
```

Is there somehow I could detect when I hit that part of the page and stop the div from moving past that.Help is much appreciated!

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zazvorniki/RTDpw/

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add a jFiddle to visualize your problem (and see your styling)? Thanks :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zazvorniki/RTDpw/ here you go! :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RTDpw/1/ This work??

Comment: Thank you, that works, but I still need them to be able to jump to the top of the page when they hit the bottom. I have very long pages and it's a pain to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the height of the page, minus the height of the div in question, as well as the footer... make sure the top is never greater than that value... you'll also need an onresize event handler re-evaluate that value.

---

looking at your jsfiddle... [here are my edits](http://jsfiddle.net/tracker1/RTDpw/6/)

In your scroll listener, I am checking for the position of the page, and adjusting the bottom position of the floater appropriately.  I also set the initial display:none, so you don't need to call .hide() in your initial script.  In addition, resizing the window has the effect of scrolling for your use, so I changed the listener for both events.

```
$(document).on('scroll resize', function (e) {
  var viewHeight = $(window).height();
  var viewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var footerTop = $("footer").offset().top;
  var baseline = (viewHeight + viewTop) - footerTop;
  var bu = $("#beamUp").css({bottom: (baseline < 0 ? 0 : baseline) + 'px'});

  if (viewTop >= 50) {
    bu.show(1000);
  } else {
    bu.hide(1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your trying to say. I can get the height of the page and then subtract the div...but I should make sure what top is never grater? Any why would I use the onresize event? What am I resizing?

Comment: Okay.. you have a page height of 1000px (top to bottom including footer), your floating item is 100px high, and the footer is 20px high.. then you should *NEVER* set the top position for the floating item over ((1000 - 100) - 20)...  the resize event, is because making the window wider/narrower will change the height of the page as a whole.

Comment: It's a back to top div though, so it needs to sit on the bottom of the page until it hits the footer. And I'm still not really understanding what your saying to do with my div. Could you give an example or something to see? I did post a jsfiddle above with what I'm working with.

Comment: Saw the jsfiddle, and just posted my edits, as well as the relevant piece in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've been playing with this for a little while now, and yes it works in that small js fiddle example, but when I throw that into a long, long page the beam me up link sits at the top of the page and is no longer fixed to follow the content, instead it just sits at the top. The whole point is to let the user to jump to the top of the page. Heres a link to what I'm actually working on http://www.writeyourfiction.com/index.php/story/readStory/342/75#

Comment: the username is username and the password is password

Comment: Don't have time to look into it..  just a guess that your JS may have an error... did you check your js console log output?

Comment: I have, and no console errors...it just didn't seem to work with long documents. It would have been nice to have an error, would have given me somewhere to go. I have since moved on and have changed the position of the go to top to the top of the screen. This solved all of my problems and actually works better on the phone...which is what I needed this for.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work in your larger environment... just the same, would appreciate if you'd check this as correct, since it does work as desired in the fiddle.